# Signing a message with a SmartCard / Yubikey

Tags: security, gnupg, digital-signature, smartcard, yubikey

So I've gone through a pretty bog-standard GPG-key-setup process, and then used `addtokey` to move said keys onto a Yubikey 4.

Now, on a fresh setup, I want to try and *use* those keys, to sign something.

After the `gpg --card-edit` **>** `fetch` **>** `quit` process, I get the following:

```
❯ Desktop gpg --list-keys
/Users/ec/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
----------------------------
pub   rsa2048/0x2BE8A417BF406E87 2018-08-16 [SC] [expires: 2020-08-15]
      Key fingerprint = 3867 0E24 7DC7 5E49 4B48  744E 2BE8 A417 BF40 6E87
uid                   [ unknown] Elliott Cable <ec@codeverse.com>
sub   rsa2048/0x7A596C9A746CB1F0 2018-08-16 [E] [expires: 2020-08-15]

❯ Desktop gpg --card-status
Reader ...........: Yubico Yubikey 4 OTP U2F CCID
Application ID ...: D2760001240102010006075491570000
Version ..........: 2.1
Manufacturer .....: Yubico
Serial number ....: 07549157
Name of cardholder: Elliott Cable
Language prefs ...: [not set]
Sex ..............: unspecified
URL of public key : https://keybase.io/elliottcable/key.asc
Login data .......: [not set]
Signature PIN ....: not forced
Key attributes ...: rsa2048 rsa2048 rsa2048
Max. PIN lengths .: 127 127 127
PIN retry counter : 3 0 3
Signature counter : 0
Signature key ....: B4F5 4290 6FF0 F1ED CC83  FA8F 8C14 9643 D99F 3060
      created ....: 2018-08-16 18:24:26
Encryption key....: B36C 0811 5520 0A59 6F5D  1F72 03AE 8E13 EAB1 F828
      created ....: 2018-08-16 18:25:02
Authentication key: C149 9C3B 42EE DBCA 0AD5  736E 2341 9C21 21A9 4D0D
      created ....: 2018-08-16 18:25:21
General key info..: [none]

❯ Desktop gpg -sa message.txt
gpg: no default secret key: No public key
gpg: signing failed: No public key
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I use this key-provisioned Yubikey to sign something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-u` option to specify which keyid to **u**se.

```
gpg --sign -u <key-id> message.txt
```

Use `gpg --list-secret-keys` to get key-id.